# assert.h conflict when compiling Boost with Android NDK

Tags: android, c++, linux, boost, android-ndk

When trying to compile a program with the Boost c++ Libraries using the Android NDK, I get the following type of error:

```
In file included from /home/afeder/android/0ad/jni/lib/boost/boost/assert.hpp:50,
                 from /home/afeder/android/0ad/jni/lib/boost/boost/random/linear_congruential.hpp:21,
                 from /home/afeder/android/0ad/jni/src/source/scriptinterface/ScriptInterface.h:34,
                 from /home/afeder/android/0ad/jni/src/source/ps/World.h:28,
                 from /home/afeder/android/0ad/jni/src/source/main.cpp:58:
/home/afeder/android/android-ndk-r7/platforms/android-5/arch-arm/usr/include/assert.h: At global scope:
/home/afeder/android/android-ndk-r7/platforms/android-5/arch-arm/usr/include/assert.h:63: warning: redundant redeclaration of 'void __assert(const char*, int, const char*)' in same scope
/home/afeder/android/android-ndk-r7/platforms/android-5/arch-arm/usr/include/assert.h:63: warning: previous declaration of 'void __assert(const char*, int, const char*)'
/home/afeder/android/android-ndk-r7/platforms/android-5/arch-arm/usr/include/assert.h:64: warning: redundant redeclaration of 'void __assert2(const char*, int, const char*, const char*)' in same scope
/home/afeder/android/android-ndk-r7/platforms/android-5/arch-arm/usr/include/assert.h:64: warning: previous declaration of 'void __assert2(const char*, int, const char*, const char*)'
```

Clearly, there is some kind of conflict between a set of "assert" functions supplied by Boost and ones supplied by the NDK itself, but how do I resolve it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Header files have #define macro which encapsulates the entire header file contents. In your source, you can prefer to undefine the header that is not required by you.

Example, if the Boost header file has #define BOOST_ASSERT_HPP and the NDK has ANDROID_ASSERT_H, in your source you can undefine the Boost related header by using #undef BOOST_ASSERT_HPP.

Comment: Those macros, known as "include guards" or "header guards", are intended to prevent multiple inclusion of the same header.  They're not intended to be referred to outside the header itself.  In any case, `#define BOOST_ASSERT_HPP`, not `#undef BOOST_ASSERT_HPP`, would prevent processing the contents of the header (if you do it *before* the `#include`).

Comment: You might be right on this. Then what is the solution to avoid mutiple inclusions?

Comment: As far as I can tell, just don't include both headers.  Probably the Boost header shouldn't be using reserved identifiers like `__assert` (unless Boost is considered part of the implementation in which case the implementation is probably buggy).